# I can see the flag link on a historically locked post from mobile

Tags: bug, status-completed, flags, mobile-web, locked-questions

Locked questions are supposed to be *locked*, that is they can't be voted, posted on, commented on or flagged. However, I noticed that while all these links are correctly absent from the normal view for a historically locked question, I can still see the **flag** link when viewing it from mobile.

Go to [Fundamental difference between Hashing and Encryption algorithms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4948322/fundamental-difference-between-hashing-and-encryption-algorithms) from a mobile (or click the **mobile** link at the footer when viewing it), the **flag** link is visible and functional:

> [image]

When I attempt to submit a flag, I get no feedback ("Thanks we'll look at it!" or "There was a problem"), and the flag isn't submitted (I don't see it in my flag history, and a mod doesn't see it there).

In addition, users with enough reputation can see the "edit tags" when hovering the tags:

> [image]

When clicking "Save Tag Edits" it brings red error "Locked questions cannot be edited".

Comment: I can see it from PC too.

Comment: @hjpotter92: Changed to a different locked question

Comment: Also worth to mention we see "edit tags" when hovering the line of tags and when clicking "Save Tag Edits" it brings red error "Locked questions cannot be edited". Think I'll add screenshots, do you mind?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: Go ahead

Comment: status-norepro here, on iOS.

Comment: @Undo you probably browse the full version. Do you see "mobile" in the footer?

Comment: @Sha I'm on iPad, and I'm on the full version, yes. Woops. Testing from mobile... Yes, reproed on Mobile, iOS 6.

Answer (score 1):

This has been fixed and will be available in the next deployment (`rev 2245` on meta and `rev 1606` on the network).